# How to get the worksheet working area range

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get the visible 'working area' range of a worksheet in VBA?

By that, I mean the range of cells that are currently visible within the confines of the application window. Scrolling either vertically or horizontally would therefore alter the cells that are visible.

The reason I ask is that I have code which once a cell within a certain range is selected, after a calculation the cell selection will jump back to the previous range. However if the previous range is 'off the screen' I would like to specify a new cell target to activate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim s As String
   Set r = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
   s = r.Address
   MsgBox (s)
End Sub
```